# How to list the values of a dataframe based on value

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some product data that I'm trying to analyse but returning the product and year where it reached a certain threshold. It looks a bit like this:

```
    Product     2006.0  2007.0  2008.0  2009.0  2010.0  2011.0
0   A           10.0    12.0    13.0    15.0    18.0    23.0
1   B           30.0    20.0    25.0    27.0    30.0    35.0
2   C           15.0    25.0    28.0    30.0    36.0    40.0
3   D           8.0     20.0    32.0    44.0    56.0    58.0
```

...

```
7   C           15.0    25.0    28.0    30.0    36.0    40.0
8   D           8.0     20.0    32.0    44.0    56.0    58.0
9   E           61.0    72.0    76.0    85.0    68.0    60.0
10  A           10.0    12.0    13.0    15.0    18.0    23.0
```

I've tried a simple apply function to run across the rows and return which year and for what product that threshold is exceeded.

I am still learning Pandas.

I did consider set_index for product and then running map across the years of data, but that doesn't appear to be very efficient.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you give an example of an input (threshold) and the expected output for that, given the example data you posted?

Comment: I want the threshold to be say 30 for a value and the output for the rows that say Product B reached that threshold in 2006 reached that threshold.

Comment: But I want a  printed list (or a dataframe) that I can chuck into Excel. As the wisdom of SO is powerful.

Comment: Provide provide a self-contained (minimal) example (no `...`) and the matching expected output

Comment: @elksie5000 Do you have duplicated products in "Product" column? It would be great if you edit your question and put there expected output.

Comment: @AndrejKesely  Yes there are duplicate products. I wanted to try a groupby but can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dot` product:

```
thresh = 30

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'\d{4}')]
df['t>30'] = df[cols].gt(thresh).dot(cols.astype(str) + ',').str.split(',').str[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Product  2006.0  2007.0  2008.0  2009.0  2010.0  2011.0    t>30
0        A    10.0    12.0    13.0    15.0    18.0    23.0        
1        B    30.0    20.0    25.0    27.0    30.0    35.0  2011.0
2        C    15.0    25.0    28.0    30.0    36.0    40.0  2010.0
3        D     8.0    20.0    32.0    44.0    56.0    58.0  2008.0
7        C    15.0    25.0    28.0    30.0    36.0    40.0  2010.0
8        D     8.0    20.0    32.0    44.0    56.0    58.0  2008.0
9        E    61.0    72.0    76.0    85.0    68.0    60.0  2006.0
10       A    10.0    12.0    13.0    15.0    18.0    23.0
```

Step by step:

```
>>> out = df[cols].gt(thresh)
    2006.0  2007.0  2008.0  2009.0  2010.0  2011.0
0    False   False   False   False   False   False
1    False   False   False   False   False    True
2    False   False   False   False    True    True
3    False   False    True    True    True    True
7    False   False   False   False    True    True
8    False   False    True    True    True    True
9     True    True    True    True    True    True
10   False   False   False   False   False   False

>>> out = out.dot(cols.astype(str) + ',')
0                                               
1                                        2011.0,
2                                 2010.0,2011.0,
3                   2008.0,2009.0,2010.0,2011.0,
7                                 2010.0,2011.0,
8                   2008.0,2009.0,2010.0,2011.0,
9     2006.0,2007.0,2008.0,2009.0,2010.0,2011.0,
10                                              
dtype: object

>>> out = out.str.split(',')
0                                                    []
1                                            [2011.0, ]
2                                    [2010.0, 2011.0, ]
3                    [2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0, 2011.0, ]
7                                    [2010.0, 2011.0, ]
8                    [2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0, 2011.0, ]
9     [2006.0, 2007.0, 2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0, 2011....
10                                                   []
dtype: object

>>> df['t>30'] = out.str[0]
0           
1     2011.0
2     2010.0
3     2008.0
7     2010.0
8     2008.0
9     2006.0
10          
Name: t>30, dtype: object
```

**Update** if you want to summarize per product, you can group by product and keep the highest value for each year (because the highest value has the most chance to exceed the threshold):

```
>>> (df.groupby('Product')[cols].max().gt(30)
       .dot(cols.astype(str) + ',').str.split(',').str[0]
       .rename('Year').reset_index())
  Product    Year
0       A        
1       B  2011.0
2       C  2010.0
3       D  2008.0
4       E  2006.0
```

Comment: @elksie5000. I updated my answer related to your last comment. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
df.set_index('Product', inplace=True)
matches = df > 30
```

Now `matches` is:

```
          2006   2007   2008   2009   2010   2011
Product                                          
A        False  False  False  False  False  False
B        False  False  False  False  False   True
C        False  False  False  False   True   True
D        False  False   True   True   True   True
C        False  False  False  False   True   True
D        False  False   True   True   True   True
E         True   True   True   True   True   True
A        False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Then you can do:

```
matches.any(0)         

2006    True
2007    True
2008    True
2009    True
2010    True
2011    True

matches.any(1)        

Product
A    False
B     True
C     True
D     True
C     True
D     True
E     True
A    False
```